# Autodesk Forge Viewer: Hide all but selected

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

While using the autodesk forge viewer, if you select a part and right-click, there is an option to "hide selected". How can i make an option (button) to hide all but selected. Would this just be the "isolate" button?
Thanks!
Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, "isolate" basically means "hide everything except this".

But if you'd like to modify the context menu anyway, that's possible, too: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/customize-viewer-context-menu.